# Regex: matching multiple patterns and getting middle of string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am working on a code that takes a bunch of SQL queries and aims to break down the queries only into the table names.

For example I have the following queries:

```
delete from pear.admin where jdjdj
delete from pear.admin_user where blah
delete from ss_pear.admin_user where blah
```

I am trying to get a `regex` that matches all these patterns, would that be 
through creating a list of multiple patterns first and then passing it 
through `str_extract` ?

I used a regex but it's giving me the following output:

```
delete from pear.admin
```

how do I get rid of the first words before it? I tried `(.*)` but nothing 
seems to work.

```
sql_data$table_name <- 
str_extract(sql_data$Full.Sql, "[^_]+\\.[\\w]+\\_[\\w]+")
```

Answer (score 4):

I am only familiar with the base R regex functions, so here is an option using `sub`:

```
queries <- c("delete from pear.admin where jdjdj",
             "delete from pear.admin_user where blah",
             "delete from ss_pear.admin_user where blah")

table_names <- sapply(queries, function(x) {
    sub(".*\\bfrom\\s+(\\S+).*", "\\1", x)
})
table_names

           1                    2                    3 
"pear.admin"    "pear.admin_user" "ss_pear.admin_user"
```

This should perform at least somewhat reliably, since, as far as I know, what immediately followed the keyword `FROM` must be a table name.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-regex approach using `strsplit` to split from `from`, and extract the first word from the second element, i.e.

```
sapply(strsplit(queries, ' from '), function(i)gsub('\\s.*', '', i[2]))
#[1] "pear.admin"         "pear.admin_user"    "ss_pear.admin_user"
```

**NOTE:** This will work If your table names *DO NOT* (and should not) have spaces in them

Comment: Not using table and column names with spaces is, at the very least, best practice.  If the table name did have spaces, it would have to be escaped with double quotes, backticks, or square brackets, depending on the particular database.  Upvoted +1 for an extremely concise answer.

Comment: what if not all the queries include from? some are "insert into" is there a way to split the first two words instead of the specific "from"

Comment: Sure, just do `strsplit(queries, ' from | insert into')`

Comment: I am trying to do this now however it is not working for everything , i did 'from|into' and it doesnt do anything for the ones with from and only fills in the "into" queries

Comment: Check for any spaces between them. You might need `' from | into '`

Answer (score 0):

I you only want what is in between `from` and `where` (from what I understood) try the following `regex`

```
gsub("(.*from )(.*)( where.*)","\\2",sql.data$Full.Sql)
```

Comment: That's not always the case though. Theres about 600 queries with different words after the table names

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
gsub(".*?from\\s(\\S+).*","\\1", sql.data$Full.Sql)
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J8Lntg/2/).

Comment: While unlikely, your pattern might admit some other word which has `from` as a substring of it.  So, to be safe, you should put a word boundary before `from`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `qdapRegex::ex_between` with no regex

```
qdapRegex::ex_between(x, "from", "where")

#[[1]]
#[1] "pear.admin"

#[[2]]
#[1] "pear.admin_user"

#[[3]]
#[1] "ss_pear.admin_user"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("delete from pear.admin where jdjdj", 
       "delete from pear.admin_user where blah", 
       "delete from ss_pear.admin_user where blah")
```

Comment: This fails should the query have one or more join clauses after the from clause.  But, it happens to work for the three sample queries provided.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not sure what join queries would look like however, there is `ex_between_multiple` which would extract multiple instances of works between "from" and "where".

Comment: E.g. in MySQL `delete from pear.admin t1 inner join other_table t2 on t1.id = t2.id where jdjdj`.  What I'm saying is that in general, the table name might not be in between `FROM` and `WHERE`.